# How to make multithreaded app with foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

Have an app which sort large txt file by some conditions.
I need to start for example 5 threads but i read line by line from file with foreach loop.
And if  I start 5 threads with my code, all threads will take same lines.

Here is my code where i start 1 thread:

```
    Thread[] thr;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        decimal value = 1;
        int i = 0;
        int j = (int)(value);
        thr = new Thread[j];
        for (; i < j; i++)
        {
            thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));
            thr[i].IsBackground = true;
            thr[i].Start();
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLineFromFile(TextReader fileReader)
    {
        using (fileReader)
        {
            string currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return currentLine;
            }
        }
    }


    public void go()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TextReader readFile = new StreamReader(file_path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
            foreach (string line in ReadLineFromFile(readFile))
            {
                if (line.Split(':')[0].Contains("@"))
                {
                    string out_line = line.Split(':')[0].Replace("+", "") + ":" + line.Split(':')[1];
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        mail_count++;
                        log_mail(mail_count);
                        mail.Add(out_line.Trim().Replace(";", ":"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string out_line = line.Split(':')[0].Replace("+", "") + ":" + line.Split(':')[1];
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        rubbish_count++;
                        log_rubbish(rubbish_count);
                        rubbish.Add(out_line.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Ready");
            BeginInvoke(
            new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button4.Enabled = false;
            }));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, whatever you do, you hard drive can only be at one position at a given time, so there is no real point "parallelizing" a file read.

You could however give an offset to each thread from which to start reading in the file, but that won't speed up anything ^^

Comment: If you really want to speed ud your function, you have to use disk caching to your advantage : start reading the file before it's actually needed. This will load the file in memory automatically (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), and then you'll be able to read it from RAM when actually needed.You can then fully exploit Pako producer-consumer pattern.

Answer (score 4):

It's no use for all threads to read the same file and reading from a shared file is difficult and inefficient.

In your main function, you would need something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(System.IO.File.ReadLines(file_path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8), 
   line => ProcessOneLine(line) 
);
```

and then ProcessOneLine would do the `.Split(':')` etc.

Comment: ProcessOneLine what is it?

Comment: You will have to write `void ProcessOneLine(string line) { ... }`. To do everything needed for 1 line. Threading is provided by the `Parallel` class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman By using Parallel.ForEach, it will read the whole file (millions lines here). Using BlockingCollection<T> to implement a producer-consumer pattern is an alternative way IMO.

Comment: @ValidfroM - I don't see the need here. My code will read the file sequentially and at most DegreeOfParallelism lines at a time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you are right. :) Parallel.ForEach(System.IO.File.ReadLines(file_path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8), new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism= XXX }
   line => ProcessOneLine(line) 
);

Answer (score 3):

Why not going with usual producer-consumer pattern? Make one thread read file, put lines in some shared collection, and other threads just pick data from the collection and process it.

More - you can read from file and for each line create `Task` that will take care of processing this line and put the result in output collection.

This seems better than 5 threads trying to read the same file and not reading the same line multiple times.

Comment: This is fine, but reading a file is probably orders of magnitude slower than the process he's doing with the file, so there's probably no point doing that.

Comment: Because I load txt file with millions lines, and if i do like you said, I'll get outmemory exception

Comment: I fully agree with you. I just wanted to give a hint on how to solve simillar problems in general. In this specific case such solution will not give expected benefits - true.

Comment: You won't get out of memory, since you clear the collection while it is filled. The consumers don't have to wait for the producer to finish reading the file, so Pako architecture is actually quite good, design-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to confirm and expand on what Pako said. The other threads should use data from a shared collection containing the data and process it.

Having multiple threads access a text file sounds like a potential for race conditions to occur. Essentially unpredictable outcomes can occur if a thread is changing a file whilst another thread is reading from it.

I've also experienced BSODs in the past when using multiple threads which access the same text file and can recommend against it. If you are insistent on doing this, however, I'd recommend you take a look at the "lock" keyword and the singleton design pattern. This will allow you to make sure that only a single thread is accessing the file at a time.

Related links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking